# Skip a line while reading a file in C

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have a problem and I haven't found a solution that works. It's really easy, but I don't understand what to do.

I have a file with some lines, like:

```
#comment

#comment

icecream 5

pizza 10

pie 7

#comment

tortillas 5
fajitas 5
```

And I want that my program just read the lines that don't start with `#`.

```
FILE *pf;
char first [20], second [20];
pf = fopen("config.conf", "r");
if (pf)
{
    while (! feof(pf))
    {
        fscanf(pf, "%s \t ", first);
        while(!strcmp(first,"#")){ `HERE I NEED JUMP TO NEXT LINE`
            fscanf(pf, "%s \t ", first);
        }
        fscanf (pf, "%s \t ", second);
        printf("Food: %s \t Cost: %s \n", first, second);
    }
    fclose(pf);
}
else
    printf( "Errore nell'aprire config.conf\n");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real way to get to the next line without reading the line that starts with the `#`. About all you can do is read that data, but ignore it.

```
char ignore[1024];

fgets(ignore, sizeof(ignore), pf);
```

Comment: I think to use another way, like
when i read the \#, start a new while that continue to read all the character until the end of line char (that i think is \n)

Comment: ok, i tryed also with your ignore. Now i have 3 different way to do that, and all working :) thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can skip to end of line without using a buffer by applying `%*[^\n]` format specifier:

```
fscanf(pf, "%*[^\n]");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to read a configuration file, then [use the right tool instead of reinventing the wheel.](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/)

---

```
while(!strcmp(first,"#")
```

is wrong. You want to filter out the lines which **start with** a hash sign, and **not** the ones which **are nothing but a hash sign.** Also, `while(!feof(f))` is wrong. Furthermore, if you're reading line by line, why bother using `fscanf()` when you can take advantage of `fgets()` instead?

All in all, that whole huge `while` loop can be simplified into something like this:

```
char buf[0x1000];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), pf) != NULL) {
    if (buf[0] == '#') continue;

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Well, the while(!feof(f)) work. and is the example that made my professor, so i'm a little confused :-D
Anyway your solution is pretty good, i just must to read from the buffer the words, but is not difficult. Thank you!

Comment: @user2299689 It may work now, but it's wrong. (I could quote examples when I fixed huge mistakes in "professors'" code examples/statements/affirmations.)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use strstr to look for the "#".

See description:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr