# C: Indexing of character arrays and using strcmp

Tags: c, string

I accidentally ran expensive simulations with an extra printf statement hidden in a for loop, creating huge ~10 GB files instead of ~10 KB files.

Re running the simulations isn't the best option so I've decided to take a crack at fixing the problem even though I don't have any formal training with C.

I'm trying to fix the problem by creating a program that reads these huge files, and prints out only the lines of the form (x, y, t, n) where (x, y, t, n are int, int, long double, long double). The other lines are a combination of strings, numbers and spaces that basically describe certain parameters, but all the (millions) of unwanted lines start with the letter "i".

So I thought I'd try to follow the example of this code here: [Skip a line while reading a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107976/skip-a-line-while-reading-a-file-in-c)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     FILE *f;

     if((f = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
     {
         printf("Couldn't open file. \n");
         return(0);
     }

     char buf[500];

     while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL)
     {

         if(strcmp(&buf[0], "i") != 0)
         {
             printf("%s \n", buf);
         }

     }
}
```

So it seems the line

```
if(strcmp(&buf[0], "i") != 0)
```

Doesn't really work, as even if the first element of a line is "i" the printf of the line still prints. Interestingly if I add this inside the if statement:

```
printf("%c \n", buf[0]);
```

"i" can still print, even though I was trying to make that the condition for failing the if statement. Interestingly, the line

```
printf("%s \n", &buf[0]);
```

Just prints the same thing as

```
printf("%s \n", buf);
```

I tried to re-write

```
if(strcmp(&buf[0], "i") != 0)
```

as

```
if(strcmp(buf[0], "i") != 0)
```

but just received an error.

How do I correctly compare the first element of each line to a chosen character "i"?

Comment: `buf[0]` is a char which you can compare with another char with `if (buf[0] == 'i')...`

Comment: Wow, so it seems I was just using " instead of ' ? *facepalm* Thanks!

Comment: `if(buf[0] != 'i') ...`

Comment: If you are using a bash shell, and just want a solution, you could use something like: `sed '/^i/ d' giant_file.txt > filtered_file.txt`.

Comment: Perhaps sed or awk can do the job for you. I know it is not a programming answer, but you dont have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strncmp()` instead of `strcmp()` for comparing the n elements of string.

`if` statement should be like `if((strncmp(buf,"i",1))!=0)`.Now it will compare only `one` element i.e the `1st` element of string stored in `buf` to `i`.

But for first element you can simply use `if(buf[0]=='i')`.

Comment: You don't need `strcmp()` to compare a single element of a string, you can just compare the character directly.

Comment: yes I kwow but in case if any one wants to cmpare 1 or some element of string,then he/she can use  `strncmp` for comparing n elements. Thanks @ Havenard.